# What does the XX-citizens tag mean?

Tags: discussion, tags

For many countries we have both XX and XX-citizens tags (e.g., [usa](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) and [us-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-citizens)), but I am not sure what the difference is. It seems to me that the idea is if you are an expat, or planning on being an expat, in the US, then you would use the [usa](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) and if you are a citizen of the US and are an expat, or planning on being an expat, in a country other than the US then you would use the [us-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-citizens). If you are an expat in the US but planning on moving to another country then it seems odd to use the [us-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-citizens) since you are not. This also happens if you are a US citizen expat living in the UK looking to move back to the US. In this case it seems you would tag the question with both [uk-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk-citizens) and [usa](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa), which seems wrong.

I think it is important to differentiate between the country you are, or planning on being, an expat in from your "home" country. I am just not sure the country you are a citizen of is the right description. The problem is that "citizen" has a specific meaning to an expat. A tag like [xx-residents](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xx-residents) might be better, but it still has very specific connotations.

Comment: Closely related: http://meta.expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/6/28

Answer (score 3):

The tag-wiki entries explain this.  Borrowing from [usa](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa):

> Use this tag for questions about living in the United States of America as an expatriate. For questions relating to living abroad as a US citizen, use [us-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-citizens).

Further expanding on your question:

> If you are an expat in the US but planning on moving to another country then it seems odd to use the [us-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-citizens) since you are not.

That's true.  If you are an expat in the US, then moving to, say, France, there would be no reason to use [us-citizen](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-citizen), unless you had actually obtained US citizenship.  You would instead use [xx-citizen](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xx-citizen), for whichever country you are a citizen, as this is what is relevant to your question when moving to France.  It will be rare that a question about moving to France will be affected by your previous residency rather than by your citizenship.

In cases where you have dual citizenship, it is appropriate to use multiple [xx-citizen](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xx-citizen) tags.

Comment: Also if you have a spouse with a different nationality to your own and you would be moving together, multiple tags would be appropriate

Answer (score 1):

I believe the idea was [country-name](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/country-name) for questions about moving to that country, and [code-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-citizens) for questions about citizens from that country going elsewhere

So, [usa](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) would be for people moving to the USA, while [uk-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk-citizens) is for questions for UK citizens going elsewhere

For example, the tag wiki for [usa](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) is currently

> Living in the United States of America as an expatriate.

While for [uk-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk-citizens) it's

> For questions pertaining to citizens of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland

Comment: I agree with the idea, but it is flawed. Not everyone leaving the UK for the US is a UK citizen (in a legal passport carrying way) and in fact some are US citizens.

Comment: @StrongBad: That's irrelevant. What matters is not where you're coming from, but where your citizenship resides. Taxes, visas, etc, have nothing to do with what countries you have visited or lived in. They have to do with your citizenship.